# black screen in kali linux 2019.2 after grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kali-linux

[image]

i was installing kali linux 2019.2 as dual boot. but as after grub it showed the above screen after that it only show a black screen with a white cursor in left upper corner. also ctrl + alt + del don't work there and i tried reinstalling but didn't worked. i searched google and found few solutions but didn't worked..

ps- i had kali 2018.1 installed but someohow it crashed and tried many solution but didn't work after that i tried to install kali 2019.2 and here i am.

I have hp laptop with intel Pentium and intel hd graphics.

Update :-- i tried 
1. adding nomodeset then it show different some audio codec error fixed that with this command "modprobe snd_hda_codec_realtek" .

2. Then i tried adding nomodeset grub_gfxmode=1280x1024x24. But this also just show a blank screen flashing cursor in left upper corner
3. Removed quiet and replaced with nomodeset and it works few times it takes me to the desktop but not always works and in display setting it say unknown display and not able to change resolution also searched unknown display in kali linux but nothing works. Okay , when i got the desktop i tried to installed graphics driver for intel hd graphics but can't find a solid manual to install. Tried apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati and radeon and intel but it say already installed newest version... nothing is working.

But when i install Ubuntu it works fine. WHY ?????????

Answer (score 1):

Probably a video driver issue.

1. While system booting menu (Grub) type e to edit the first grub line
2. Find the line that starts with linux and ends with quiet. Add nomodeset after the word quiet.
3. You should be able to boot into the GUI
4. Do an "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade" from the command line.
5. Find and install the video drivers for your specific video card.

Comment: Didn't worked but something happens. Now it show a different error. [21.665573] hdaudio hdaudioCOD2 : Unable to bind the codec

Comment: Okay . So, now i fixed that error with this command " modprobe snd_hda_codec_realtek "  and now there is just a blinking cursor.

Comment: Well the blinking cursor means your display manager is screwed up somehow. Have you tried Ctrl-Alt-F# (a function key, try any one) until you get to a terminal?

Comment: Ubuntu is installing and booting just fine like butter...but kali linux is not booting. I always face problems in kali . linux..  

Comment: Yes , i tried . it boot in kali  tty2 with terminal... What to do after that.... But how Ubuntu is booting fine without any error... Even i fully formated my hdd . Still i am getting this problem

Comment: I have the exact same error, @KaranMalhotra, did you find a solution?

Comment: Real heroes don't wear capes

Answer (score 0):

At Boot select recovery mode, there ensure internet connection by starting network-manager service than update and upgrade the system.
apt update,
apt upgrade

apt dist-upgrade

and reboot. Worked for me after a lot of looking around.
Hope it works, cheers!